# How to create a custom map report

Tags: sql-server, ssrs, spatial

not sure if this is the right forum. But just wondering is there a way one can make a map report out of an image or a map made on excel. I have the data and I've looked around and found that its possible to edit world maps, etc, to show information. Is it possible to make a simple map from scratch, to show something like a floor plan, something that isn't available on google maps. 
Thanks guys in advance sorry if I'm not being clear on what I'm asking. If i can be clearer please ask.

Note: I'm currently using SSRS and QGIS to try do this. I have the data i need to show but don't have the co-ordinates for the thing i want to show. I thought that could be something i could do when I'm making the map. Only a small map to show one piece of information about 200 distinct data points.

Comment: Have you found a suitable solution yet? If you're happy with either of the answers below can you please mark the question as answered.

Comment: Sorry i'm new to this, i'll do that now thank again guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a full answer as I haven't ever used SRSS for mapping, however reading the comments on Peter's answer it would appear that you need to create some spatial data to work with.

Here's a simple example of how you could put build spatial data for a seating plan without having to use GIS software.  Once that is done it should just be a matter of joining to the HallSeating table with your exam/student data.

```
-- Create the hall
CREATE TABLE HallOutline (
    MyID INT IDENTITY(1,1)  NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    SHAPE Geometry
);

INSERT INTO HallOutLine (SHAPE)
VALUES (
    Geometry::STGeomFromText(
        'LINESTRING (0 0, 20 0, 20 50, 0 50, 0 0)' -- Simple 20 x 50 box
        ,0 -- SRID is 0 for all the data
    )
);

-- Create seating plan
CREATE TABLE HallSeating (
    MyID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    Row INT NOT NULL, -- I'm using row and column as a key to the
    Col INT NOT NULL, -- exam data, but you could use anything.
    SHAPE Geometry
);

INSERT INTO HallSeating(Row, Col, Shape)
SELECT Row, 
       Col, 
       Geometry::STGeomFromText(
         Concat('Point (',XLocation,' ',YLocation,')') -- Point location of the seat
         ,0 -- 0 SRID again
       ).STBuffer(.5) -- Create circle diameter 1 at seat location
FROM (VALUES(1,40), (2,37), (3,34), (4,31), (5,28), (6,25), (7,22), (8,19), (9,16), (10,13), (11,10), (12,7))  AS R(Row,YLocation), -- Rows
    (VALUES(1,2), (2,3), (3,4), (4,5), (5,6), (6,7), (7,8), (8,11), (9,12), (10,13), (11,14), (12,15), (13,16), (14,17), (15,18))  AS C(Col,XLocation) -- Columns
```

This creates a plan that looks like this

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Short version is yes its possible to do what you are describing.

Your report will have a spatial query to display the shapes you want. Whether that's a map or a floor plan.

You can then add analytical data in a second query to colour the map. The two queries needs to be joined by a key. 
Im not familiar with qgis but ideally you'd want both the spatial data and analytics in sql server.

The other option is to have 2 layers. The first layer gives the 'map' shape and the 2nd adds points on top.

If you search Google images for "SSRS map" you'll see lots of examples.

Comment: Thanks Peter for the reply, my database doesn't have co-ordinates and i was hoping i could 'assign'  the points rather than write a spatial query. All (I only have the names and other info for the floor plan as well as an image of the floor plan itself ) But if that's what i have to do then i'll give it a go.  Olivia

Comment: Hi. If you think of it like a normal sql query you need to join the 2 datasets. I guess the other option would be to give the data xy points and plot them on top of your polygons. Like pins on a map.

Comment: What coordinate system are you using?

Comment: that's the problem i don't have one i need to assign coordinates to my data points

Comment: the pins on the map could work the plan will be like a grid as far as i know

Comment: Sorry I missed that point. So then im wondering if this needs to be spatial at all. Does your floor plan have coordinates? Im assuming so if it's in qgis. Yes?

Comment: Not sure if i need them too, my floor plan is just and exam hall with chair and i need to be able to hover of the 'chair' and give me the details of the person sitting there,. I've gotten all the info i need through a query off the database and i have as i said an image of a floorplan but my problem is connecting the two, i'm not sure how to do that part or as you said what software to even use.

Comment: looking back up at your answer its the shapefile i think i'm confused about how can one make a custom one out of an image all i've seen is world maps.

Comment: Ok. So the answer to this question is. Yes it can be done in ssrs. However whether ssrs is the best tool for the job depends on a whole lot of factors. I would say you could do what you describe with a web page. Just html, css and an image for the floor plan. But I don't know what the broader context is. How many users? Internal use or Web site. Static data or changing/dynamic?

Comment: Yeah the data would be dynamic different students would be sitting exams , students could be sitting in 2 different chairs for both exams etc. yeah i agree with you there, but the report will be part of the oracle server so need to have it to pass through ssrs at some stage for it to work for me, i'd also want to color code the points based on other factors. Think i can start i now anyway thanks Peter!

Comment: @Olivia ahh. Ok. So maps (like maps of usa states) are actually made up of lots of shapes (polygons) which can be stored together in sql server in geometry or geography data types. If you can draw the floor plan in gqis including however the floor is divided and give each area a label, then you could treat it like a map.

Comment: thats could work too yes my problem is how to draw that floor plan, most of the tutorials i've found so far deal with editing existing maps or importing from google maps etc.

Comment: Ok. Plan b. I think you could also do this with a static image in ssrs and lots of expressions. Location of chair 1. Add a text box with an expression to find student assigned to chair 1. Etc etc.

Comment: that what i started on there! I was thinking it should should work as the map won't change, only the information with it. thanks Peter!